# Php sql Left Join Tables Echo columns from table 1

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables blog and tbl_users. blog contains columns 'blogid','message','title','name','created' & 'image_ctgy'.  tbl_users contains columns 'userPic', 'image_ctgy', 'userId'. The code below displays the blog message and the associated images with that blog messsage based on the same image_ctgy. However my knowledge of php is limited and I am having difficulty in displaying the title, name & created columns along with the blog message. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$sql = "SELECT blog.message as blogmessage, tbl_users.userPic as tblPics
FROM blog
LEFT JOIN tbl_users ON(blog.image_ctgy = tbl_users.image_ctgy)
ORDER by blog.blogid DESC";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$blogs = array();
while (($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)))
{
$blogmessage = $row['blogmessage'];
$blogs[$blogmessage] [] = $row['tblPics'];
}
?>

<html>
<body>
<?php
    foreach ($blogs as $blogmessage => $tblPics)
    {
?>
    <h2><?php echo $blogmessage; ?></h2>

    <ul>
<?php
    foreach ($tblPics as $tblPic)
    {
 ?>
        <li> <img src="cms3/user_images/<?php echo $tblPic; ?>"width="50px" height="50px"/></li>

<?php
    }
 ?>
    </ul>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to get fields title, name, created along with message and userPic:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT blog.message as blogmessage, blog.title, blog.name, blog.created,  tbl_users.userPic as tblPics
FROM blog
LEFT JOIN tbl_users ON(blog.image_ctgy = tbl_users.image_ctgy)
ORDER by blog.blogid DESC";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$blogs = array();
while (($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)))
{
    // here you can get along with blogmessage another desired columns:
    // title, name, created
$blogmessage = $row['blogmessage'];
$blogs[$blogmessage] [] = $row['tblPics'];
}
?>

<html>
<body>
<?php
foreach ($blogs as $blogmessage => $tblPics)
{
    ?>
    <h2><?php echo $blogmessage; ?></h2>

    <ul>
        <?php
        foreach ($tblPics as $tblPic)
        {
            ?>
            <li> <img src="cms3/user_images/<?php echo $tblPic; ?>"width="50px" height="50px"/></li>

            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank for your suggestion - but have failed to incorporate title, name and created (date) successfully. Are you able to provide suggested coding. I have searched extensively on stackoverflow but have not found a solution.